# Fraction function from fractions module python problem

Tags: python, fractions

```
>>> n=F.Fraction(3.56)
>>> n
Fraction(8016407336719483, 2251799813685248)
>>> n=F.Fraction('3.56')
>>> n
Fraction(89, 25)
```

Is it working as intended? Both results are correct, but the first one seems to be over the top.
I stubmled it upon while solving [this](https://www.codewars.com/kata/54f8693ea58bce689100065f) kata from codewars.

Comment: The float `3.56` does not represent exactly one hundredth of 356. If you want exactly one hundredth of 356, you should use `'3.56'`, to avoid floating-point rounding error. (Floating-point rounding error doesn't go away when you pass a float to `Fraction`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the usual issues with binary floating-point, the Fraction(floating) doesn't return the expected fraction object, different from the decimal or string, that is treated like a exact number.

But you can treat this issue using a method called "limit_denominator" that have a default argument "max_denominator=1000000",so, you only need to call:

```
Fraction(3.16).limit_denominator()
```

Take a look at the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction.limit_denominator

Answer (score 1):

When you wrote `3.56`, it means you declared a number `3.56` as **float** type. And float type has a small deviation, which cause there's also a small deviation when it converts to fraction type.

But when you wrote `'3.56'`, you declared a string. String has a limited length, thus there's no more deviation. When you convert it to string, they will convert it to the exact value.

See also: https://www.daniweb.com/programming/threads/506664/mod-unexpected-result